# C++ output 0 to 99998 and result in repeat output 2060

Tags: c++

I try to output 0 to 99998 in c++,but it output to 2060 and repeat.
I want to know where the problem is.And I have check **multitest** file. It save 0 to 99998.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void Multi_DataWrite_write()
{
    FILE *fd = fopen("multitest", "w");
    if (fd == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Files Error" << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
    {
        double ii = i;
        fwrite(&ii, sizeof(double), 1, fd);
    }
    fclose(fd);

    FILE *fdr = fopen("multitest", "r");
    ofstream out;
    out.open("multiread", std::ios::out);

    for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
    {
        double ii;
        fread(&ii, sizeof(double), 1, fdr);
        out << ii;
        out << endl;
    }

    fclose(fdr);

}



int main()
{
    Multi_DataWrite_write();
    return 0;
}
```

and the **multiread** files result

[image]

I have try to adjust the location of **double ii;**, and it seems no effect. So I seek for help.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try using binary mode?

Comment: For a start, you should be checking that all those reads and writes are actually *working!*

Comment: @Yunnosch multitest is binary mode.

Comment: @paxdiablo I have checked multitest and it is working.But multiread files result isn't right

Comment: Actually, your code gives me the correct result: `multiread` has the correct values.

Comment: I use visual studio 2015,and I try to run program in CLion.It works.It seems vs problem.Thanks!